# ¿Cómo crear un directorio mediante la API RESTSHARP?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

Estoy implementado un sistema de migración en C# y para realizar la migración requiero usar REST. Para esto encontré el cliente RESTSHARP pero no sé como hacer que me cree un directorio en el servidor. ¿Alguien tiene una idea de como realizar esta operación?

Comment: Hola Alex, biienvenid@ a [es.so], ¿has echado un ojo a la documentación oficial?

Comment: Sí, ya la he revisado, pero no entiendo como hacer la creación del directorio.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Podrías poner el código con el que probaste?

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener presente que el propósito de `Restsharp`es actuar como un cliente `rest`, esto es básicamente, enviar mensajes `http` osea, consumir el determinado servicio `http`. **Por si solo Restsharp no puede crear un directorio, no es su propósito.**

Si lo que deseas es que al consumir el servicio se cree determinado directorio en el servidor, lo que debes tener es un método (acción) en tu api que haga dicha tarea.

Por ejemplo, que tengas en tu `api`tengas un metodo: `http://midominio/api/createdirectory`ya teniendo este método que crea el directo dentro de las operaciones de tu api, lo puedes invocar con Restsharp o con el cliente rest de tu preferencia.